# How to subtract two dynamic ranges and paste it to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a macro that copies two dynamic table columns from one worksheet to another. On the Second worksheet I want to subtract those two columns and paste the result on a separate column/vector. All of this needs to be dynamic since I plan on running the macro once a day.

The closest I have come is the following code:

```
Sub Makro2()

Dim ws_3 As Worksheet
Set ws_3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)


Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws_3.Range("E3:E400").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"

End Sub
```

So all I need in reality is for E3:E400 to be dynamic since the range of the other two columns change every day.

PS. Rather new at VBA.

Comment: In what way do the two ranges change? Do they change in size? Position? Are there blank cells in the column?

Comment: Use the last row from column D, there are multiple examples on SO

Comment: Are the ranges defined with the Name Manager as dynamic ranges?

Comment: See GMalc's answer below which should help you. As an aside, your code doesn't have any Copy Paste function so you do not need code line `Application.CutCopyMode = False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic, ensure you declare your variable.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E3:E" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 =
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, rng1  As Range, rng2 As Range, LastColumn As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Data appears here
        Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Sheet2") '<- Data will be copy here
    End With

    With wsSource
        'Let's say the two columns we want to copy is column A & B. Find Last row of A & B
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        'Create the ranges you want to copy
        Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow1)
        Set rng2 = .Range("B1:B" & LastRow2)
    End With

    With wsDestination
        'Paste column after the last column of row 1. Find last column row 1
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        rng1.Copy
        .Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        rng2.Copy
        .Cells(1, LastColumn + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```